# Output not being seen as expected - can someone help

Tags: visualforce

This is the Trailhead question :

Using a Standard List Controller, create a Visualforce page which displays a list of Accounts with links to their respective record detail pages.
The page must be named 'AccountList'.
It must reference the Account standard controller.
It must have a recordSetVar equal to 'accounts'.
It must have a Visualforce apex:repeat component.
The repeater must have the var attribute set to 'a'.
The repeater must use the `<li>` HTML list tag
The repeater must use the apex:outputLink component to link to the respective record detail page
HINT: Record detail pages can be reached by placing a record ID at the root of the URL (e.g. '/')

This is my Code answer for the same .. but the Output visualforce page doesnot display the list of accounts as expected - though the salesforce trailhead says challenge complete - can someone help

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
 <apex:form >


 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockSection title=" List of Accounts">

 <apex:repeat value="{! accounts}" var="a">

 <ul>
  <li>



 <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, a.Id )}"
 rendered="True" disabled="False" onclick="View">


 </apex:outputLink>

 </li>
 </ul>

 </apex:repeat>

 </apex:pageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>


 </apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some text inside this tag `<apex:outputLink ...></apex:outputLink>` such as:

```
 <apex:outputLink ...>{!a.Name}</apex:outputLink>
```

as otherwise the link is not visible or clickable.

(I also suggest you get into the habit of removing blank lines that have no purpose and of indenting nested elements; that will make it easier for you to see the structure of your pages or code.)

Comment: Keith thanks for the input : Made this change :<apex:outputLink value="https://ap2.salesforce.com/apex/AccountDetail?core.apexpages.request.
 devconsole=1&id={! a.id}"
  rendered="True" disabled="False" onclick="View" onfocus="Display">{!a.Name}
   </apex:outputLink>
 This works but suprisingly gives this error  :Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
The page does not bind to the record ID value (in order to link to the record detail page).

Comment: @RajivV.Subramanian That's a separate question really. But based on what you posted it sounds like they are looking for is `value="/{!a.id}"`.